# No Payment Methods in Magento (2checkout)

Tags: magento, methods

I have Installed Magento ver. 1.9.1.0
I have installed 2 payment gateways from Admin sid, those are 1) 2checkout and 2) Paymentwall

I have enabled both payment gateways from Admin panel, But the problem comes here..

when i go to front end, i select a recurring product, I filled out payment information, i clicked on CONTINUE.

HERE THE PROBLEM COMES!!!

THERE COMES MESSAGE: "no payment method"

EVEN IF I CLICK ON CONTINUE, I GET THIS MESSAGE " your order cannot be completed at this time, as there is no payment method available for you "

I am fed up with it. Please someone help me with this, to get through this...

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem here is that you're trying to checkout for a product that is setup for recurring payment. If you try and checkout with a normal product do they appear then?

I'm currently in the same boat as you, and trying to work out a way to setup recurring payments using the WorldPay plugin but it seems this function only works with "Express Checkout" (assuming PayPal) which is annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Check your allowed Shipping/Billing Countries from backend. Best way is to enable any default magento payment method and check if it is working correctly.

Comment: **Stores -> Configuration -> General -> General -> Country Options**

Answer (score 0):

Enabling "Saved CC" Method works for me
try enabling that method